# WSO2 returns error response for all APIs including sample API(pizzashack)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have published my apis in wso2-publisher and am trying to access from the store(wso2). but it gives response as follows:

**Response Body :** no content

**Response Code :** 0

**Response Header :** no response from server

It may be duplicate of 
[WSO2 API Manager "error": "no response from server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272302/wso2-api-manager-error-no-response-from-server). But i am not able to get the response for sample API itself(Pizzashack API).

I have tried all the ways suggested there but no luck.

Also i faced the same problem while i was running the wso2-api-manager in my AWS instance. Is there any separate change needed in api-manager for VMs?

Can anybody help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the curl command work for you? If so, accept the certificate first and then invoke the API from the browser.

Comment: But through curl how can i get the certificate? Can you please explain me on this?

Comment: @Vineeth You need to access the url in browser, not in curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Troubleshooting**
>
> When using the API Console, the web browser sends an HTTPS request to
>   the Gateway. If the certificate in the Gateway is not CA signed, the
>   browser will not accept it. Therefore, you may get the following
>   error.
>
> ```
> ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
> ```
>
> As a workaround, you can access the Gateway URL on a new browser tab
>   and trust the certificate from the browser.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-InvokingtheAPI